# SP2013 SharePoint-hosted app Modal Dialog Error: Cannot read 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm just trying to prove the concept of displaying a modal dialog in my SharePoint-hosted app page.  I believe I've included the required js libraries and I give it more than enough time to load the libraries before I execute my function.  The error I receive is:

***Cannot read property 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog' of undefined***

I believe I have the libraries I need::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDialog() {

var optDict = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    title: "Upload your file"
};

try {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(optDict);
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error `Cannot read property 'hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog' of undefined` occurs since the  sp.ui.dialog.js is globalized JavaScript library and the required resource file `SP.Res.resx` has not been loaded on the client side (`SP.Res.hiddenButtonValueBeforeDialog` is generated from this file).

### Solution

1. `ScriptResx` HTTP Handler is used to load the content of resource
   files on the client side, the following line has to added:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us"></script>
   ```
2. In addition, since there is a dependency for `SP.UI.UIUtility`
   namespace in `sp.ui.dialog.js` library, the `sp.init.js` JavaScript
   library has to be referenced:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: This was what I needed.  So it's a limitation of needing more pieces/parts for the HTML page that would typically already be there for a ASPX page.

Comment: I have done this, but get the error 'The object does not support the property or method "_dlgWndTop".' ... am I missing another reference?

Comment: Ok I was still missing some references ... now I don't get any error ... but the dialog still doesn't appear ... ;)

Comment: Instead of accessing ScriptResx.ashx I referenced SP.Res.js directly   <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Res.js"></script>
which worked for me. I'm not sure if there are any pros and cons of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I added all these references in PlaceHolderMain

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/1033/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/ie55up.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/inplview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/cui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.ribbon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/mdn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.pub.ribbon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/msstring.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/socialdata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.socialribbon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/cui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/wpadder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now all javascript errors are gone